# 403 status on deleting modules through gcloud preview app

Tags: gcloud

I currently use
`gcloud preview app modules delete <module_name> --version <version_to_delete>` with a service account to clean up old module versions for managed vms. This has been working great up until last week. I am now getting the error below.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.modules.delete) Error Response: [403] Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
Details: [[{"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help", "links": [{"description": "Google developer console API activation", "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/<project_id>/apiui/api"}]}]]
```

More specifics:

1. Using my personal account from google allows me to delete module versions
2. I currently set the service account with `gcloud auth activate-service-account <some_id>@developer.gserviceaccount.com --key-file gcloud.json`

Comment: AppEngine team is looking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must enable the "App Engine Admin API" in the Developers Console in order to delete modules using a service account:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/
2. Navigate to **APIs and auth > APIs**
3. Find and enable "App Engine Admin API"